# bash - Possible to 'override' the test ([[)-builtin?

Tags: bash

Is it possible to override Bash's test builtin? So that

```
[[ $1 = 'a' ]]
```

not just does the test but also outputs which result was expected when it fails? Something like

```
echo "Expected $1 to be a.'
```

**EDIT**

I know this is bad :-).

Comment: I don't think you can override an operator in bash -- it isn't that kind of language -- and it really looks a bit like shooting ants with a bazooka :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The test expression compound command does real short-circuiting that affects all expansions.

```
$ set -x
$ [[ 0 -gt x=1+1 || ++x -eq $(tee /dev/fd/3 <<<$x) && $(echo 'nope' >&3) ]] 3>&1
+ [[ 0 -gt x=1+1 ]]
++ tee /dev/fd/2
2
+ [[ ++x -eq 2 ]]
```

So yes you *could* do anything in a single test expression. In reality it's quite rare to have a test produce a side-effect, and almost never used to produce output.

Also yes, reserved words can be overridden. Bash is more lenient with ksh-style function definitions than POSIX style (which still allows some invalid names).

```
function [[ { [ "${@:1:${#@}-1}" ]; }; \[[ -a -o -a -o -a ]] || echo lulz
```

---

Yet another forky bomb.

```
if function function if function if if \function & then \if & fi && \if & then \function & fi && then \function fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
if [[ $1 == 'a' ]]; then
    echo "all right";
else
    echo 'Expected $1 to be "a"'
fi
```

Anyway, what's the point of the test if you only expect one answer? Or do you mean that for debugging purposes?

Answer (score 1):

```
[[ 'a' = 'a' ]] || echo "failed"
[[ 'b' = 'a' ]] || echo "failed"
failed
```